# Code igniter adds an "Order by" to custom query

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter-3

On a simple custom query, CodeIgniter adds an "Order by" clause. The query is

```
  $sql = "SELECT city_location  
            FROM admin_users  
            WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['admin']['user_id'] . " 
            ORDER BY id asc 
            LIMIT 1";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

The result is after I run  $query = $this->db->query($sql) is:

```
ERROR: column "name" does not exist LINE 4: ORDER BY "name" ASC ^

SELECT "city_location" 
        FROM "admin_users" 
        WHERE "id" = '61' 
        ORDER BY "name" 
        ASC LIMIT 1
```

Questin is: why codeigniter adds a default ORDER BY to my query. The model does not contain any default ordering.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will try this cod$this->db->select('city_location');// Column name

```
$this->db->from('admin_users');// Table name
$this->db->where('id' , $_SESSION['admin']['user_id']);// Your condition Here.First parameter is columnname and second one is value
$this->db->order_by('id');
```

Comment: Thank for the tip. I've refactored my code in order to eliminate that order by. I was confused why CI adds that default order by when not using the query building